# VOIP Packets: dissecting STUN as RTP

Tags: voip, wireshark, rtp, stun, wireshark-dissector

In my pcap file, I was expecting to see RTP packets, but has STUN packets. So in wireshark, I tried to do "decode as: RTP". Packets are decoded as RTP but as "malformed packets.". Is there any way to dissect STUN to RTP ??

Comment: RTP media packets are not normally encapsulated in STUN.  STUN is common to see in connection setup and as a keep-alive mechanism between nodes of a voip/p2p session. It will use the same port as the RTP media packets.  So it is expected to have STUN packets in your capture trace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they really *are* STUN packets, and your expectations weren't met.  We'd have to see the capture in order to tell.